# Defining a well-order on $\mathbb{ N ^{3}}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Here's the question:

> Define a well-order on the set $\mathbb{ N ^{3}}$ (i.e enumerate/list the elements of $\mathbb{ N ^{3}}$)

I somehow think that the set $\mathbb{ N ^{3}}$ and $\mathbb R$ have the same cardinality. Thus there would be no enumeration.

What I don't understand :

1. How do we define least element here ? (in $\mathbb{N}^3$)
2. How is a well-ordering on the set related to enumeration?

Comment: Note that there are well-orders on $\Bbb N^3$ that are not enumerations, e.g., the [lexicographic order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order).

Answer (score 0):

$\mathbb{N}^3$ is countable, so it does not have the same cardinality as $\mathbb{R}$. To define a well order you can take any enumeration and use the well ordering of the natural numbers (if you have a bijective mapping $f$ form the natural numbers then you can always define the order on the image by the order of the preimages, i.e., $x<y$ iff $f^{-1}(x)<f^{-1}(y)$).

To get an idea of how to contruct a specific enumeration you can use as inspiration the various examples of enumerations of the rationals (which are similar to $\mathbb{N}^2$)

Comment: I'm not able to see why $\mathbb{N}^3$ is countable. Can you explain?

Comment: This is exactly what you ahow when you construct an enumeration: you show that you can "count" all elements. Just think of $\mathbb{N}^3$ as a subset of  $\mathbb{R}^3$. One possible approach is now that you start counting from the origin and first count all points closest to the origin and proceed outwards, e.g., $(1,1,1), (1,1,2), (1,2,1), (2,1,1),(1,2,2), (2,1,2), (2,2,1), \dots$ Another approach is to first count all elements that sum to 3 then all that sum to 4, etc. because all of these are finitely many, this works just fine

Comment: Got it. $(1,1,1), (1,1,2), (1,2,1), (2,1,1),(1,2,2), (2,1,2), (2,2,1), \dots$ is an enumeration. How does that relate to a well-ordering on $\mathbb{N}^3$ ?

Comment: The basic idea is to just write a $<$ between all elements in this enumeration ;) more formally as in my original answer.

Comment: Given that $(\mathbb{N}, <=)$ is a well order, I need to construct a relation between $\mathbb{N}^3$ and $\mathbb{N}$ ?

Comment: Yes, and an enumeration is exactly this relation.

Comment: Since the enumeration is based on the distance, how do I construct a well order on $\mathbb{N}^3$ from it?

Comment: I don't see the connection you make here. Why should the construction prevent you from defining a well order? No matter how you did your enumeration it will always imply a well ordering by simply using the corresponding order of the natural numbers.

Comment: My question: How do I put the well order in formal terms?